# Programming a recursive method to calculate number of groups with n elements and k groups

Tags: java, recursion

Precondition: 0 < k <= n 
Your method needs to return the number of ways k groups can be formed out of n distinct items. For example, there are 3 ways to form 2 groups out of 3 items:
 1. (a) (b,c)   2. (b) (a,c)   3. (c) (a,b)
and there are 6 ways to form 3 groups out of 4 items:
 1. (a) (b,c) (d)   2. (a) (b) (c,d)   3. (a) (c) (b,d)
 4. (a,b) (c) (d)   5. (b) (a,c) (d)   6. (b) (c) (a,d)

So far I have

```
    public static int groups (int n, int k){
    if(n==k){
        return n;
    }else if(n>1 && k==1){
        return 1;
    }else return n*groups(n-1, k-1);
}
```

I don't even know where to go for recursive on this. I see no way to break it down into smaller subproblems because once you do you start counting possibilities twice. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> I see no way to break it down into smaller subproblems because once you do you start counting possibilities twice.

This is not true. Once you create the first group, the items in the first group are *no longer in the set of candidate items*, and the subproblem becomes counting all possible groupings of the remaining items - which, by no coincidence, is the same as the original problem (count all possible groupings of a set of items).

So, then, your problem boils down to having to count all possible permutations of items in a *single* group (e.g. a, ab, ac, bc, abc), then for each of those, proceeding similarly with the remaining items.

Once you are able to determine the number of permutations for a single group with N available objects, the end result is that number plus, for each of those permutations, the number of permutations for a group that doesn't include the already grouped items (N minus group size). And so on, until you reach your base case, which is that the number of groupings of 0 items is 0.

If you can determine how to find the number of permutations of N objects (where permutations don't have to include every object), then you've got this solved already.